# "What were you doing when the app crashed?" Recovery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

**UPDATED! Check after the photo.**

All,

I was playing with an iPhone application today (Photovine) and noticed a feature that I would LOVE to include in my application. I was adding a photo to the application when the application crahed. No big deal I thought, I'll just reopen it. When I reopened it, BAM, a UIAlertView popped up with a small text box that asked me "What were you doing when the app crashed?"

I thought this was an AWESOME feature, but in my 10 second search before posting a question I couldn't find how to implement it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

**EDIT: For anyone that tries this, remember to sync your `NSUserDefaults` to make it work correctly. The `NSUserDefaults` method works perfectly if you synchronize it after writing it to YES. Just call `[NSUserDefaults synchronize];` and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code - but the main idea:

1. When the application starts, you save some property, let's say "creash" as YES.
2. When you close normally the application, you set it to NO.

Now, when you start the application, you check if this property is set to YES or NO to indicate a crash.

Comment: How would I know if the application closed normally vs not?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861738/ios-app-lifecycle-4-3gs-ipad-vs-2g-3g

Comment: Assuming it would exit through one of the regular methods within the UIApplicationDelegate which would "reset" this flag.

Comment: Nice and simple, just use one flag vs time comparison. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can install handlers for the conditions which cause your program to terminate (uncaught exceptions and signals) and set a flag which you check on launch. For detailed information on catching exceptions and signals, see this [Cocoa with Love post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html).

This code will install handlers for uncaught exceptions and signals which cause your program to shutdown.

```
void InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);
    signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGILL, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGFPE, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGBUS, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SignalHandler);
}
```

The `SignalHandler` and `HandleException` functions should:

1. Set a flag using `NSUserDefaults` to indicate the crash, and store any other information which could be helpful (such as the time, so you can tell which data goes with which crash).
2. Remove the signal or exception handler so step 3 causes a crash.
3. Resend the signal or exception. This will cause the actual crash, creating a crash log.

In your `didFinishLunchingWithOptions:` method, you should check for this flag. If you find it, you display the window to gather information from the user and send it to yourself. Then clear the flag.

Comment: @James The post I linked suggests calling it with a delay of 0 from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to ensure the run loop is set up. Crashes before that wouldn't be caught, but your program really shouldn't crash before that.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the app sets a flag when the app terminates normally.  If the app loads and the flag is not set then throw up the dialog.

Check out the app delegate method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: How would I know if the application closed normally vs not?

Comment: Added the method that would get called.  HTH Dave.

Comment: This won't be called if the application is quit from the multitasking bar. Your program simply receives a SIGKILL. Since you can't catch a SIGKILL, it is easier to catch crash conditions instead.

Comment: ughoavgfhw: how would you recommend doing it then?

Comment: @James Catch the crash. See my answer for details.

Comment: Interesting answer ughoavghw, not sure i understand why you setting and resetting the flag when the app enters the background and resumes will not work.  Most apps in the background are in a suspended state and this would work fine for what James is after.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use the `NSUserDefaults` to log the time the application is launched or moved to the foreground, then when the application is terminated or moved to the background you can log an exit time (because in the background Apple can terminate your application at any time without notice). On each launch just make sure that the application close time is > than the application launch time, otherwise it was probably a crash.